# Rationalizing The multiplicative inverse of $a + b \sqrt{2}$ to be the form $c + d \sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from Serge Lang's basic mathematics.
as stated in the title the goal of the question is to demonstrate $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}$ may be written in the form $c + d \sqrt{2}$.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out the solution from $\frac{a - b \sqrt{2}}{a^2 - 2b^2}$ back to $a + b \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you know a rule like $$\frac{A+B}{C} = \frac{A}{C}+\frac{B}{C}$$ Apply that.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematical formulas.

Comment: @LeeMosher noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rationalize the denominator of $\frac1{a+b\sqrt{2}}$ use the conjugate $a-b\sqrt{2}$ to multiply by $1$ as $$\frac1{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a-b\sqrt{2}}\frac1{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}$$ and so we have it in the form $c+d\sqrt{2}$ with $$c= \frac a{a^2-2b^2}, d = \frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}$$

Comment: oh, thank you. i was confused. didnt think it was already simplified as much as possible.

Comment: @amadecember I would just add that there is nothing special about the $2$ in the $\sqrt{2}$ term either and this works for any integer including negative numbers.

Comment: gotcha gotcha. good to know.